# Get the shortest leaf node with a non-zero gini in Decision Tree

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, binary-search-tree, decision-tree

I am trying to get the the shortest leaf node with a non-zero gini. For that, I am trying to get the depth of a decision tree at each corresponding leaf nodes. I have looked into the documentation but haven't been able to come across anything. Any suggestions on this ?

Comment: Might https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-tree-plot-unveil-tree-structure-py help?

Comment: Yes. This one only helped. Thanks